# Ubuntu 18.04 Broke my server

Tags: server, ssh, openssh

When I try to ssh into my ubuntu server, I have this shell input and output.

```
sjrsimac@SethDanicaTV:~$ ssh -vvv sjrsimac@SethServer
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "sethserver" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname sethserver: Name or service not known
```

On my server, I opened /etc/ssh/ssh_config and changed `*` to `SethServer`, but the debug message still claims it's reading a `*`. What are these debug messages asking me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug messages are telling you that you need to provide a mechanism to resolve the host name `SethServer` into an actual IP address.

For example, supposing that `SethServer` is on your local LAN with IPv4 address 192.168.1.11, you could do one of the folowing:

1. add a stanza to your **local** SSH client configuration file `~/.ssh/config` something like

   ```
   Host            SethServer
     HostName      192.168.1.11
   ```
2. add an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file

   ```
   192.168.1.11    SethServer
   ```
3. configure your DNS server to provide resolution for `SethServer`

Comment: Item #1 worked on my ubuntu machine, and just typing my server's local IP address worked on my windows 10 machine, but this solution feels semipermanent. Can I pair a MAC address to a hostname?

Comment: @SethReuter Solutions for Windows 10 would be outside the scope of this site - unless you are referring to a WSL installation (in which case the above solutions should work there as well)